# Gearbox vibrates vibrates on 1st gear and reverse

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, vibration, opel, astra

Opel astr g z18xe 2001.i have just changed my clutch plate only not the pressure and flywheel plate. Gear box vibrates when it is on 1st gear even on reverse. Why?

Comment: A mounting left loose or you got grease or oil on the centre plate

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you should have replaced the pressure plate and flywheel when you had the work done. If the friction disk is toast, more than likely the PP/FW also need to be renewed.